# PHP get value from class without modifying existing class

Tags: php

I am using the following [Coinbase PHP api](https://github.com/ricog/coinbase-exchange-php/tree/master/lib/CoinbaseExchange):

The class file includes the following line:

```
 * An array of API endpoints
 */
 public $endpoints = array(
 'book' => array('method' => 'GET', 'uri' => '/products/%s/book'),
 );

 public function getOrderBook($product = 'BTC-EUR') {
 //$this->validate('product', $product);
 return $this->request('book', array('id' => $product));
 }
```

In my file I call it using:

```
$exchange = new CoinbaseExchange();//Connect to Coinbase API
$getOrderbook = $exchange->getOrderBook();
print_r($getOrderbook);
```

Nothing is returned.

Though if I modify the class from:

```
'book' => array('method' => 'GET', 'uri' => '/products/%s/book'),
```

To:

```
'book' => array('method' => 'GET', 'uri' => '/products/%s/book?level=2'),
```

I get the desired out put in my file.

How can I leave the class as `'book' => array('method' => 'GET', 'uri' => '/products/%s/book'),` as it is calling it through `$getOrderbook = $exchange->getOrderBook();`. Where do I include 'level=2` in the latter line please?

Answer (score 2):

As the property `$endpoints` is public, you can access it from outside of class (see below):

```
$exchange = new CoinbaseExchange();//Connect to Coinbase API
$exchange->endpoints = array('book' => array('method' => 'GET', 'uri' => '/products/%s/book?level=2'))
$getOrderbook = $exchange->getOrderBook();
print_r($getOrderbook);
```

Comment: You are replacing all endpoints and calling some other method may lead to error.

Comment: I have just tried to show that op can update `$endpoint` outside of class (I don't think it will lead to error). however op can only update the uri part, as you shown in your answer

Comment: I thought I could do something similar to this `$getOrderbook = $exchange->getOrderBook([`level=2);` but it didn't work

Comment: no that won't work, as it is not suppose to take endpoint as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can make temporary changes to endpoint:

```
$oldEndpoint= $exchange->endpoints['book']; // save previous value
$exchange->endpoints['book']['uri'] .= '?level=2'; // make needed changes
$exchange->getOrderBook();
$exchange->endpoints['book'] = $oldEndpoint; // reset to old value
```